# join different column in one of them- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i am in python and i have a data frame like the following

```
col1     col2
4         
3
            5
6
7
            8
```

i want to merge two columns if the first contain no values , i write the following code put it didn't run , it just return the col1 values as it is and did'nt add col2 values, i want to know what the wrong with it

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['col2'] if x['col1'] == ''   else x['col1'], axis=1)
```

i want the output of col1 to be as the following

```
col1  
4
3
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: `df['col1']=df.replace('',np.nan).bfill(1).iloc[:,0]` ?

Comment: please , clarify your answer , as i didn't understand it

Comment: i want to  replace nan values with values in col2

Comment: did you check the code if it works though? I am replacing blanks with `np.nan` and backfilling on axis 1 and then just taking the first column

Comment: and in my code i will write np.nan rather than ' ' ? right

Comment: you dont need apply for this, with the example you have shared you have `''` <- blanks. in this case use the code I have provided in the comment, or use `df=df.replace('',np.nan)` then 
`df['col1']=df[['col1','col2']].bfill(1).iloc[:,0]`

Comment: Use `df['col1']= df['col1'].fillna(df['col2'])` or better: `df['col1']= pd.to_numeric(df['col1'],errors = 'coerce').fillna(df['col2'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of your blanks may be `''`, so we can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors = 'coerce'` and then fill in the `NaN` values ​​with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'],errors = 'coerce').fillna(df['col2'])
```

Comment: Yes actually better to use `to_numeric` here +1

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = { 'col1' : ['4', '3', ' ', '6', '7', ' '],
      'col2' : [' ', ' ', '5', ' ', ' ', '8']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)
df

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
     if df.loc[i]['col1'] == ' ':
            df.loc[i]['col1'] = df.loc[i]['col2']      
df.drop('col2', axis=1)
```

Comment: this is terribly slow, it is preferable to use panda methods that are designed to do these tasks